# Django "Table already exists" on testing

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I've tried to solve the following issue: 
I'm running `python manage.py test` to test my application. 
After creating a new test_app database, I'm getting

> DatabaseError: (1050, "Table 'auth_group' already exists")

I haven't installed South (it's not on the INSTALLED_APPS list), how do I solve this?

Comment: Are you saying that you are creating the database?

Comment: test_app is auto created after  running the command..

Comment: Is there a stacktrace with that error?

Comment: Did you write your own tests? Any of them creates DB or table? A traceback would help.

Comment: Are yocreating the user factory twice ?

Comment: I haven't written any new tests, there's just the tests.py file on my app folder

Comment: Please, show your `DATABASES` and `INSTALLED_APPS` settings.

Comment: I just commented out the django.contrib.* lines

Comment: I've had similar stuff with columns when applying squashed migrations. If you have any squashed files, make sure it is not doing the same operation twice.

Answer (score 0):

Install south is the best way for django

You should use south like this if be the first one:

```
    python manage.py syncdb --settings= SETTINGS_NAME
    python manage.py convert_to_south APP_NAME --settings= SETTINGS_NAME
    python manage.py schemamigration APP_NAME --initial --settings= SETTINGS_NAME
    python manage.py migrate APP_NAME --fake --settings= SETTINGS_NAME
```

If you made the migrations use the following sentences:

```
    python manage.py schemamigration APP_NAME --auto
    python manage.py migrate APP_NAME --settings= SETTINGS_NAME)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use python manage.py migrate app_name rather than python manage.py migrate.Because you had used it before